# django - default value migration - will this touch database?

Tags: mysql, django

I want to make new migration which contains only new default values for some fields. But the database table has >10.000.000 rows (MySQL) and ~200.000 users online.

so what I generally dont know is: does the default value migration (or migrations like choicefield changes) touch the database?

I know that migrations like adding, deleting do touch the database to create/delete stuffs.

would be grateful for some useful tips and links if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't touch the database.

[It does not effect the behavior of setting defaults in the database directly - Django never sets database defaults and always applies them in the Django ORM code.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.AlterField)

(in fact applying such migrations only marks them as applied and that's all, no real work is performed)